# Returning an object that conforms to a generic constraint

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I am trying to create a `Builder` for my `ComplexObject`:

```
import Foundation

class ComplexObject {
    // lots of stuff

    init<ObjectType, T>(_ closure: ((ObjectType) -> T)) {
        // lots of init/setup code
    }

    // other initializers with generics, constructed 
    // by other Builders than ConcreteBuilder<O> below
}

protocol BuilderType {
    associatedtype ObjectType
    func title(_: String) -> Self
    func build<T>(_ closure: ((ObjectType) -> T)) -> ComplexObject
}

struct Injected<O> {
    //...
}

extension ComplexObject {
    static func newBuilder<Builder: BuilderType, O>(someDependency: Injected<O>) -> Builder where Builder.ObjectType == O {
        // vvvv
        return ConcreteBuilder(someDependency: someDependency)
        // ^^^^
        // Cannot convert return expression of type 'ComplexObject.ConcreteBuilder<O>' to return type 'Builder'
    }

    struct ConcreteBuilder<O>: BuilderType {
        private let dependency: Injected<O>

        private var title: String

        init(someDependency: Injected<O>) {
            self.dependency = someDependency
        }

        func title(_ title: String) -> ConcreteBuilder<O> {
            var builder = self
            builder.title = title
            return builder
        }

        func build<T>(_ closure: ((O) -> T)) -> ComplexObject {
            return ComplexObject(closure)
        }
    }
}
```

but `swiftc` complains about the `return ConcreteBuilder(...)` line

`Cannot convert return expression of type 'ComplexObject.ConcreteBuilder<O>' to return type 'Builder'`

I also tried

```
static func newBuilder<Builder: BuilderType>(someDependency: Injected<Builder.ObjectType>) -> Builder {
    return ConcreteBuilder(someDependency: someDependency)
}
```

with the same result. I see that I could just expose `ConcreteBuilder`, but I hoped to be able to hide that implementation detail. What am I missing here?

Comment: Consider whether you really need the `BuilderType` protocol – what other types would conform to it? I suspect that you really just want `func newBuilder` to return `ConcreteBuilder<O>`, in which case you can completely get rid of the protocol.

Comment: The initial problem was that `ComplexObject` has multiple initializers with different type constraints, e.g. `ComplexObject.init<T: SomeProtocol>(instance: T)`, `ComplexObject<U: SomeOtherProtocol>(providerOfU: ((Int) -> U))` etc. with different (optional) arguments controlling `ComplexObject`'s behavior. Initially, I intended to have a single `Builder` for all these initializers, but that didn't quite work, so I thought I could have multiple `Builder`s hidden behind some factory method overloads for `newBuilder`.

Comment: This feels like a misuse of protocols; what do you want the *calling* code to look like? What would you expect the caller to do with the result of `newBuilder`? `Complex.init` is particularly confusing. What does it do with `closure`? Why does `Injected` exist? This feels like it was built starting with generics and protocols, which will generally get you into corners. Instead, you want to start with callers and a few concrete implementations, and then extract the generics and protocols.

Comment: I assume you're trying to build some kind of Java-style Builder pattern. That's fine; it's just not clear why it's generic. What do the other implementations of `BuilderType` look like?

Comment: I left out some details in an attempt to scope my question a bit. My actual Builder class has some more operations with generic arguments. My 'ComplexObject'  class is a `ViewModel` that converts a model (`ObjectType`) to (an array of) `T: CellViewModel` instances that can be bound to a tableView's cells.
My actual Builder uses `ObjectType` at several ocasions. For example, there is a `func itemSelected(_ itemSelected: AnyObserver<ObjectType>?) -> Self` in BuilderType, too. I might have to refactor

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to solve this issue, but the root of the problem is that `newBuilder(someDependancy:)` has a generic type signature, but it's really not generic.

Its return type asserts that function can return an object  of any type `T: BuilderType where Builder.ObjectType == O`, but that's clearly not the case. Asking this function to return any type besides a `ConcreteBuilder` isn't supported. At best, you could use a force cast, but if someone writes `let myBuilder: MyBuilder = ComplexObject.newBuilder(someDependancy: dec)`, the code would crash (even if `MyBuilder` satisfies your generic constraints) because you're trying to force cast `ConcreteBuilder` to `MyBuilder`.

As far as a solution... I don't have one. Fundamentally you just want to return `BuilderType`, but I don't think that's possible because it has an associated type.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do ?

```
return ConcreteBuilder(someDependency: someDependency) as! Builder
```

Comment: Yes, that fixes the build error. But when I try to use the `Builder`, I get `Generic parameter 'O' could not be inferred`. I also don't see why the force-cast should be necessary here.